# Python Selenium on Firefox: Button Find by Xpath - Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have been automating Firefox using selenium.

Code used:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@class="btn btn-warning"]').click()
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="HideCheckPunchPopup()">
```

Error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //button[@class="btn btn-warning"]
```

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the application if it can be accessed in public?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.